# Why are some <div> not updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am starting with the HTML5/JavaScript/jQuery stack and quickly ran into a problem. I want to update the content of a `<div>` with values via jQuery.

All the code below is at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qpux4wyq/1/).

The `HTML` part:

```
<body>
  <div class="root">
    <div class="current">
      <div class="date1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="date2"></div>
    <div class="calendar"></div>
    <div class="status"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="infoscreen.js"></script>
</body>
```

Content of `infoscreen.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("ready!");
        update();
    });

function update() {
    $(".current").text("current");
    $(".date1").text("date1");
    $(".date2").text("date2");
    $(".calendar").text("calendar");
    $(".status").text("status");
}
```

The problem is with the `<div class="date1">` and `<div class="date2">`. The first one is not updated via the jQuery query, while the second one is.

Is there a special way to address a nested `<div>`? I do not think so as all of them are children of  `<div class="root">` anyway (and I did not need to refer to the class `root`)

Comment: its because you are overriding content inside current on update use prepend on your current div http://jsfiddle.net/qpux4wyq/2/

Comment: the issue you are removing the `<div class="date1">` while setting ` $(".current").text("current");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `$(".current").text("current");` overwrites the complete contents of the `<div>` and thus the `<div>` with the class `date1` is not there anymore. Just right-click the element in your browser and choose *"inspect element"* to see this.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that "$(".current").text("current");" is setting the content of the div with class "current" with the text "current", so the div that this element had before is disappearing. You can see it by reviewing the rendered code in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any problem here.
The only problem I think is you did not include jquery script here kindly add this before `infoscreen.js` see below .
`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="infoscreen.js"></script>`

Comment: please see this line `$(".current").text("current");` he is overwriting the all the contents in `.current`